# What does the ic stand for in ic-ajax

Tags: ember.js, ic-ajax

Is ic in ic-ajax an acronym or a phonetic pronunciation of something?

Can't find anything on google or the library README.md.

Comment: Eh, use ember-fetch if you can :)

Comment: @knownasilya thanks for the heads up!  Definitely gonna switch out to ember-fetch now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [list of Instructure's GitHub projects](https://github.com/instructure/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=ic), it seems to be their vendor prefix. I'd guess *InstruCture-* or *InstructureComponent-*.